# Embedding Uglified Javascript into a Jade template

Tags: javascript, pug, gruntjs, uglifyjs

I have a project that uses grunt to build my site from a Jade template and also builds and concatenates JavaScript using an uglify task (grunt-contrib-uglify).

As I am building a single page app, rather than link to the external uglified version of my JavaScript I would like to build the uglified version into my jade template and save on the extra http request.

Within my grunt file, how can I get uglify to pass its content into the my Jade template rather than build it as an external file?

Any thoughts welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to simply pass the uglified javascript string as [data for your jade template](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jade#data). For the jade task, use a function for your data key which reads and returns the contents of the uglified file (using [grunt.file.read](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.read) for example).

Obviously ensure your uglified task is run before your jade task.

Comment: Yep this was the conclusion I had come to. There doesn't seem to be a way of avoiding writing the JavaScript file and instead capturing the output of the uglify process in a variable. Thanks for your response.